# Could Wormtail Have Harmed Lupin or Fenrir Greyback With His Silver Hand?

Tags: harry-potter

Both Remus Lupin and Fenrir Greyback were werewolves. **If Wormtail had grabbed onto to one or the other with his silver hand, would the magical hand have disabled or killed either werewolf?** Would it depend on which part of the body grabbed onto? Or in traditional werewolf lore is silver touching against any part of the body enough to be debilitating or lethal?

Comment: Is there anything at all in Potterverse canon that addresses silver and werewolves?  There are enough things that are just slightly different in the potterverse that it wouldn't surprise me if the reason silver is never mentioned is just because it's a "muggle superstition".  In more traditional werewolf lore, silver burns just by touching skin - like a severe allergy.  (At least in the universes that come to mind - Anita Blake, Underworld, and others.)

Comment: Do we even know if the hand is silver, or if it just looks like silver?

Comment: Wormtail’s sobbing stopped abruptly. His breathing harsh
and ragged, he raised his head and stared in disbelief at the silver hand, now attached seamlessly to his arm, as though he were wearing a dazzling glove. - *GoF* - *The Death Eaters* I guess you'll have to parse it as you see fit. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - doesn't proove anything, IMHO. There was also a "silver doe" in the text as far as I recall, obviously meaning "silver colored", so there's precedent.

Comment: @DVK - Like I said people will have to parse it as they see fit. I really don't have a solid opinion one way or another. . . yet. I suppose I did take "silver hand" as being silver at face value, but who knows? Perhaps it's really platinum or Mithril. I can certainly think of reasons why silver would be impractical (it's soft; it tarnishes; etc)  :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - imagine what a silver hand would **weigh**

Comment: Folk tails disagree how vampires can be killed.  Some say they can killed only by silver weapons, or only by a silver *bullet to the heart*, or a wooden stake through their heart, or garlic, sun light, holy water, fire, by ordinary damage but only when they are transformed to a bat, or by killing the oldest vampires first.  Vampires are also “immortal”.  There's similar confusion about how you can kill a werewolf.  Which of these apply to the Potterverse is hard to guess.

Comment: Btw, I also believe that Pettigrew's hand isn't actually made of silver, but weight itself doesn't prove this as we know about enchantments that reduce the weight of objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JKR was never very clear on this but she obviously was aware of silver connection.

From http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/rumours_view.cfm?id=38 (retrieved via Wayback machine):

> **Section: Rumours**
>
> *Peter Pettigrew's silver hand will be used to kill Remus Lupin*
>
> JKR: Nice idea, clearly predicated on the legend that only a silver bullet can kill a werewolf – but incorrect.

Now, this may be parsed in 2 ways: as "incorrect because silver hand is no threat to Lupin" for whatever reason, OR merely as "No, Lupin will NOT be killed by that hand, independently of whether he can be".

---

On a side note, one can also not read anything unambiguous into the "silver hand" word choice (as opposed to silver haired hand) - elsewhere in the books she uses "silver doe" to mean silver colored doe.

---

One consideration that would indicate it's not **real** silver is that the hand made out of actual silver would likely be a bit too heavy to be useful.

Comment: Considering that originally it's silver to kill a *vampire* she may mean that the legend is 'incorrect'.

Comment: @Pureferret - good point. I'm not familiar enough with werewolf lore to know if they are supposed to be silver weak but I think you're right.